# Foreign key did not update with primary key in oracle

Tags: oracle

i'm using oracle 11g r2 Express Edition and SQL Command line. i'm getting problem when i update the primary key the foreign key did not update. is there any solution?

this is the command for my 2 table

```
CREATE TABLE staff(staff_id number(5) not null primary key);

CREATE TABLE customer(customer_id number(5) not null primary key,staff_id number(5) not null references staff);
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the behavior you expect to see.  A primary key should be non-volatile (unchanging).  A foreign key will not do a cascading update.  You can do something like this to implement cascading updates http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2009/10/httpasktomoraclecomtkyteupdatecascade.html but that's generally something you ought to avoid by making the primary key non-volatile to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly did you do?
What is your SQL statement?

Did you updated the primary key to a value that is consistent with some row in the customer table? Are you sure there was a corresponding row in the customer table?

Comment: i'm updating the primary key staff_id in table staff with the value 100 and the staff_id in customer table which is the foreign key did not update the value. When i'm viewing the staff_id in staff table it show the value 100 while the staff_id in customer table did not have any value.